# Duplicate tags without making more variables

Tags: javascript

So in short I want to  add a simple javascript code that add unorder list and inside of it add 4 lists with different text. I can just do this the simple way but I want to know if I can duplicate a tag `<li>` while changing the text inside without creating more variables.

```js
const ul = document.createElement('ul')
const li = document.createElement('li')
const a = ['one','two',"three","four"]

const group = document.body.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin' , ul)
ul.appendChild(li)
li.textContent = a[0]
```

Comment: Did you try with cloneNode() ? Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the `a` array and create element inside that instead.

If you want to try to avoid creating variables when not needed, you can use `appendChild` (which returns the appended element):

```js
const ul = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
for (const item of ['one','two',"three","four"]) {
  ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).textContent = item;
}
```

Another method:

```js
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'))
  .innerHTML = ['one','two',"three","four"]
    .map(t => `<li>${t}</li>`)
    .join('');
```

That said, it's better not to be afraid of creating variables if they make code more readable.